# Professor wants to change my thesis' interpretation in favor of his research. How to react?

Tags: research-process, thesis, professorship, research-undergraduate

I am about to finish my undergraduate thesis. The interpretation/conclusion i wrote is basically a statement which matches well with research of other groups and has a widely accepted scientific background.

After letting my supervisor (who has been mentoring me) and then my professor(who gave me the topic and is in charge of the decisions in the group) control my thesis, my professor wants me to edit my interpretation and write one which mainly goes along his research but is not widely accepted in science.

My supervisor said I should do what my professor asks me to.
Should I?

Edit: My professor asked me to change because I had no clear evidence for my assumptions. But I would not have any evidence for his suggestions neither.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Can you also [edit] to add what reason your professor gave when suggesting the change?

Comment: By supervisor I mean advisor, by professor the main person in charge. I edited the post.

Comment: It sounds like there may be potential arguments in favour of both interpretations. First pin down what they are - then you're in a better position to have a discussion with your professor. It may turn out that one of you is unambiguously right - and that's a good way of finding out. More likely, there are arguments for both interpretations, in which case you might be best off presenting both together with some critical analysis. TL/DR: Follow the evidence. Without providing any evidence, neither of you is demonstrably right.

Comment: @StuartGolodetz Sounds like an answe. Can you post it as one?

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like there may be potential arguments in favour of both interpretations. First pin down what they are - then you're in a better position to have a discussion with your professor. It may turn out that one of you is unambiguously right - and that's a good way of finding out. More likely, there are arguments for both interpretations, in which case you might be best off presenting both together with some critical analysis.

TL/DR: Follow the evidence. Without providing any evidence, neither of you is demonstrably right.

Answer (score 5):

If you have no clear evidence for interpretation/conclusion A (drafted already, by you) or for  interpretation/conclusion B (suggested by your professor), then it sounds like it's time to draft a new ending to your write-up.  How about the following:

Lay out A, with some supporting argumentation.

Lay out B, with some supporting argumentation.

Both would be worded as conjectures.

Then talk about what work would be needed to be able to support or rule out one or the other.

And then comes your Bibliography!

Since this is not a PhD thesis, you can sit on the fence.

Answer (score 2):

Stick to the truth:

- Write up the results that you obtained (which are the facts of various kinds).
- Say that "I conjecture that [A is true]."
- Say that "In a personal communication, [insert name here] suggested that [B is true]."

Answer (score 0):

You should bear in mind who will be marking your thesis and later on writing letters of recommendation. If you want to stick in the same field for later study, people who hire you will almost ask either your supervisor or the professor in your group of their opinion of you. You should offer some concession to the professor. Maybe a good middle ground would be to evaluate both viewpoints, and lay out the whole field as aparente001 suggests. If you really think your interpretation is right, maybe you should talk to the professor about it, and see if (s)he can persuade you or vice-versa. Note that if you are going to dispute this with the professor you really need to be understand the debate, with well thought out reasoning (not just "big wig professor" says so).

At the same time, intellectual dishonesty on your part helps nobody - don't write a conclusion you can't stand behind and defend.